# Leaves that fall off Brussels Sprouts, any reason not to cook?

Tags: brussels-sprouts

A lot of recipes recommend removing the outer leaves from Brussels Sprouts.

I understand why'd you remove brown or damaged leaves but I've always thought the leaves that just fall off are perfectly fine to eat.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones that fall off because you've accidentally trimmed off too much stem are fine to cook, although likely to overcook when treated the same as full size sprouts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safety reason not to cook them, but if they are falling off the little brussel sprout head, they probably are past their prime and won't be as good s the ones still firmly attached.  It should be a fairly small loss; I would recommend discarding them.

Answer (score -1):

finely chop some bacon and toss in the pan. When bacon is about finished toss in the extra leaves to cook down sightly.  Not the healthiest of servings but a fantastic flavor! Or mince bacon and leaves and ad to a dip for a festive holiday piece of happiness.

Comment: While this may be a good option, it doesn't really answer the question.